# svg text does not appear

Tags: svg, text

I use svg to draw soe geographic data. In order to do that i set my viewbox to match a real world and I use GPS coordinates. I want to draw a circle by given coordinates and write some text inside it. Circle is ok, but where is text? Below is a fiddle example.

```html
<svg 
 id="svg"
 width="1000" height="1000"
 viewBox="27.9043663 -43.2012437 0.0366674 0.0366674"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"  
 shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
 >
  
  <circle cx=27.9227000 cy=-43.1829100 r="0.016667" style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:0.00016667;" fill="none"/>
  <text x=27.9227000 y=-43.1829100 fill="#000"  font-family="'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" font-size="12">test</text>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is very big. So big that your circle stays within the gaps of the text. Try `font-size=".014"`. I'm afraid smaller than this won't render.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh;}
```

```html
<svg 
 id="svg"
 viewBox="27.9043663 -43.2012437 0.0366674 0.0366674"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"  
 shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
 >
  
  <circle cx=27.9227000 cy=-43.1829100 r="0.016667" style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:0.00016667;" fill="none"/>
  <text x=27.91 y=-43.179 fill="#000"  font-family="'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" font-size=".014">test</text>
  </svg>
```

I would recomend reading about [The Limits of Numbers in SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html)

Comment: Thank you. That was the reason. Obviously i must scale my coordinates.